# Custom font won't be used on chromebook but works fine in (mac) chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

Got [this little project](https://github.com/Norfeldt/weather-widget-google-calendar-extension) where I inject a weather widget into google calendar. I wish to use a google font with the widget. My attempt with an npm package (previous commits) worked fine in chrome (on a mac), but not on the chromebook tablet that I want to use it on.

I then changed tactic to inject a link tag like this

```js
console.log('Weather widget extension for google calendar executing')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log({ event })

  const linkElement = document.createElement('link')
  linkElement.rel = 'stylesheet'
  linkElement.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gemunu+Libre'
  document.head.appendChild(linkElement)
  console.log({ linkElement })

  const mainDiv = document.createElement('div')
  mainDiv.className = 'weather-widget__main'
  mainDiv.setAttribute(
    'style',
    `position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(145deg, #024acf0a, #0721d74f);
  opacity: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #0721d74f;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #0721d74f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Gemunu Libre, Roboto;
`
  )
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv)
...
```

this also works in chrome but not on the chromebook?

---

Not that it is relevant but I'm writing it in typescript and using vite with a plugin to build it. If you want to use it you have make a `.env` file

> .env

```
VITE_API_KEY=<your openweathermap api key>
VITE_LAT=<your lattitude>
VITE_LON=<your longitude>
```

run `yarn build` and [load the `dist` folder as a local extension in chrome](https://superuser.com/a/247654/145379).

### Solution

Setting the custom font by inline styling in each block seem to do the trick

(Doing `font-family: inherit;` did not work)

Comment: I do not have a chromebook so unable to debug, but here are some suggestions. Outside extension env, is there some js/css/html setup that works for you on chromebook, to render the font correctly? If yes, then you will want to do the same in the extension. There should not be anything special about it being an extension that would disable use of font, except maybe permissions or csp related issue, which can be bypassed by including the fonts in the extension source. Note that adding custom DOM to a page, the original page can override styles and fonts, unless using a shadow dom.

Comment: It's weird right? I did find a solution, but I don't understand why there is a difference between the desktop and chromebook version and why it had to be so tricky.